# Modify template in directive (dynamically adding another directive)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

## Problem

Dynamically add the *ng-bind* attribute through a custom directive to be able to use *ng-bind, ng-bind-html* or *ng-bind-html-unsafe* in a custom directive with out manually adding to the template definition everywhere.

## Example

http://jsfiddle.net/nstuart/hUxp7/2/

#### Broken Directive

```
angular.module('app').directive('bindTest', [
'$compile',
function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        compile: function (tElem, tAttrs) {
            if (!tElem.attr('ng-bind')) {
                tElem.attr('ng-bind', 'content');
                $compile(tElem)
            }
            return function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                console.log('Linking...');
                scope.content = "Content!";
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

## Solution

No idea. Really I can not figure out why something like the above fiddle doesn't work. Tried it with and with out the extra *$compile* in there.

## Workaround

I can work around it might adding a *template* value in the directive, but that wraps the content in an extra div, and I would like to be able to that if possible. (See fiddle)

## Second Workaround

See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nstuart/hUxp7/4/ (as suggested by Dr. Ikarus below). I'm considering this a workaround for right now, because it still feels like you should be able to modify the template before you get to the linking function and the changes should be found/applied.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the compiling part inside the linking function, like this:

```
angular.module('app').directive('bindTest', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: {
            post: function(scope, element, attrs){
                if (!element.attr('ng-bind')) {
                    element.attr('ng-bind', 'content');
                    var compiledElement = $compile(element)(scope);
                }
                console.log('Linking...');
                scope.content = "Content!";                
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Let me know how well this worked for you http://jsfiddle.net/bPCFj/

Comment: Got something similar working here http://jsfiddle.net/nstuart/hUxp7/4/  Would still like some understanding on to why the original does not work. I understand the compile function is where you should make template changes, so why is this one not getting picked up?

Comment: In http://jsfiddle.net/nstuart/hUxp7/4/ $compile(tElem) does not work because $compile() returns a link function, which has to be binded to a scope. Since there's no scope available in the compile step, you can't use $compile there.

Hence it's completely normal to use the $compile function in the linking step tho, so I wouldn't say it's just a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, and I figured out the $compile() not working in ..erm...compile because of the missing scope. But my original question still stands, why does altering the template not seem to do anything here? 
The $compile was my attempt at hacking it to work (which failed).

Comment: Aren't you supposed to do sth with the `compiledElement` after it is created? Does Angular understand with this code that `element` will now be replaced by `compiledElement`?

Answer (score 2):

This way seems more elegant (no dependency with $compile) and appropriate to your case :

```
angular.module('app').directive('myCustomDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        template: function(tElem, tAttrs) {
            return tAttrs['ng-bind'];
        },
        link: function (scope, elem) {
            scope.content = "Happy!";
        }
    };
});
```

jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hUxp7/8/

From [Angular directive documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) : 
*You can specify template as a string representing the template or as a function which takes two arguments tElement and tAttrs (described in the compile function api below) and returns a string value representing the template.*

Answer (score 1):

The source code tells all! Check out the [`compileNodes()` function and its use of `collectDirectives()`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L431).

First, `collectDirectives` finds all the directives on a single node. After we've collected all the directives on that node, *then* the directives are applied to the node.

So when your `compile` function on the `bindTest` directive executes, the running `$compile()` is past the point of collecting the directives to compile.

The extra call to `$compile` in your `bindTest` directive won't work because you are not linking the directive to the `$scope`. You don't have access to the `$scope` in the `compile` function, but you can use the same strategy in a `link` function where you do have access to the `$scope`

Answer (score 1):

You guys were so close.

```
function MyDirective($compile) {
    function compileMyDirective(tElement) {
        tElement.attr('ng-bind', 'someScopeProp');

        return postLinkMyDirective;
    }

    function postLinkMyDirective(iScope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        if (!('ngBind' in iAttrs)) {
            // Before $compile is run below, `ng-bind` is just a DOM attribute
            // and thus is not in iAttrs yet.
            $compile(iElement)(iScope);
        }
    }

    var defObj = {
        compile: compileMyDirective,
        scope: {
            someScopeProp: '=myDirective'
        }
    };

    return defObj;
}
```

The result will be:

```
<ANY my-directive="'hello'" ng-bind="someScopeProp">hello</ANY>
```